# Storybook: Type Errors with Angular project and fullcalendar lib

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, typescript-typings, storybook

When configure the Storybook(6.5) with Angular (15) I got the next errors:

```
Error: node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/ts3.9/index.d.ts:18:13 - error TS2724: 'React' has no exported member named 'ReactElement'. Did you mean 'createElement'?

18 }) => React.ReactElement;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
Error: node_modules/@storybook/theming/dist/ts3.9/index.d.ts:106:70 - error TS2724: 'React' has no exported member named 'ComponentType'. Did you mean 'Component'?

106 export declare type CreateStyledComponentExtrinsic<Tag extends React.ComponentType<any>, ExtraProps, Theme extends object> = CreateStyledComponentBase<PropsOf<Tag>, ExtraProps, Theme>;
                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

...
```

Answer (score 2):

After the short investigation I found the root: the conflict between the typings of Storybook **react** lib and the fullcalendar(6.1) **preact** lib.

The one way to make them working together I found
is to set the `skipLibCheck` flag to be `true` for `compilerOptions` inside the `.storybook/tsconfig.json`

I hope, this can help to someone!
BR